# Google Maps Help (Multiroute Map 4 questions)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I modified this demo because it did almost everything I needed.
http://joshdcompton.com/google_maps/mult_directions/test.html
Just need help with the following in **bold**

**Change the color so each route is a different color?** ***-SOLVED-***

tried using part of my last script but it broke the page

```
polylineOptions.strokeColor="#ff0000";
polylineOptions.strokeOpacity=.6;
polylineOptions.strokeWeight=3;
```

**Change the color of the marker to match the path?**
Tried more scripts than I can count and have never gotten any to work.

**Add a single marker (routes with only 1 stop)?**
Script works great but on  **if(JL==1){** The page breaks.

**Add information to the info balloon?**

I'll need to show job type, customer name and time.

I am an amateur coder and a lot of this code is a little above my skill level but I was able to make some of the changes I needed.
Here is my complete code

HTML

```
<body onLoad="initialize();">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:650px; height: 650px; margin:auto; background-color: #999;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var start;
var rendererOptions = {
        draggable: true,
    };
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;   

jobs1 = [{location:"3660 Las Vegas Blvd S #12 Las Vegas, NV 89109"},{location:"3978 SPANISH BARB LAS VEGAS, NV 89122"}];    
jobs2 = [{location:"4722 Cecile Ave Las Vegas NV 89115"}];
jobs3 = [{location:"1554 W Warm Springs Rd HENDERSON NV 89014"},{location:"8715 Orvieto Dr LAS VEGAS NV 89117"},{location:"3514 LA SCALA CT. NORTH LAS VEGAS NV 89032"}];   

var polylineOpts1 = {map: map,strokeColor:'#0000ff', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}
var polylineOpts2 = {map: map,strokeColor:'#00ff00', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}
var polylineOpts3 = {map: map,strokeColor:'#ff0000', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}

var markerOpts1 = {map: map,icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_greenA.png'}
var markerOpts2 = {map: map,icon:'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'}
var markerOpts3 = {map: map,icon:'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png'}


function initialize(){
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var lasvegas = new google.maps.LatLng(42.277817,-83.733673);
var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: lasvegas,
}
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    requestDirections(i);       
}
}

function renderDirections(result , p) {
var polylineOpts = eval("polylineOpts"+p)
var markerOpts = eval("markerOpts"+p)

    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions: polylineOpts,
        markerOptions:markerOpts,
    });
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
}
    function requestDirections(p) {
job=eval("jobs"+p)
JL=job.length
start=job[0]['location']
end=job[job.length-1]['location']
job.shift();
job.pop();
    directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
optimizeWaypoints: true,
    waypoints: job,
destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(result) {
    renderDirections(result,p);
});
}
```

Any help or tips would be great

Comment: it look like i need to use addListener instead of DirectionsServices but I can't figure out how to make it work.  I have tried duplicating the code with addListener.  Sorry guys this is my 1st time working with classes.  I am amateur but I am getting some of this figured out.

Comment: going though the goolge code i thought

Comment: Going though the goolge code I thought
 if(JL==1){
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, start, placemarker(start));
 
  }
would work but it just breaks the code.
I cant figure out why 

function placeMarker(location) {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }
 
 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
}
  
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cam some one please help I have been beating my head against my keyboard since Friday and have not gotten any help

Comment: Could I get some help please none of this is working.  Any solutions please.  This is beyond frustrating.  I have searched through every place a marker script I can find and all the code is simular but when I add the code to my script it breaks.  I must have it in the wrong spot or not naming a var correct.  I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big question, in fact it seems like it should really be 4 separate questions.  You might want to split it up.  Also you should try and simplify the code, get it working (your link doesn't work for me), then use that as the basis for a question on, for example, how to colour your directions in different colours.

So, dealing just with question 1, the [DirectionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest) doesn't take a polylineOptions object, which is what you tried to do here:

```
//polyline options don't exactly work
//var polylineOpts = {map: map, strokeColor:'#000000', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
function requestDirections(start, end) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        destination: end,
        //polylineOptions: polylineOpts,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING
    }, function(result) {
        renderDirections(result);
    });
}
```

However the [DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) class does.  e.g. this should set a colour:

```
var polylineOpts = {map: map, strokeColor:'#000000', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}
var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  polylineOptions: polylineOpts
});
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate you help very much.  i got the color to change just working on making each one a different color.

Comment: Got each path to be a different color. Now I'm trying to change the markers colors to match correctly. I got the markers to change but the letters (A,B,C.ect) disappeared. colors match though :) I think I will need to hide the markers and place them with <br>
    new google.maps.MarkerImage<br>
Is there a better way. Also I don't understand what<br>
    {map: map, strokeColor:'#000000', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}
is  i see how it works but how can I do this
    "{map: map, strokeColor:'"+color+"', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}"

Comment: sorry, new with this can't figure out how to display code I'll separate my 2 questions in 2 comments below.

Comment: What is **{map: map, strokeColor:'#000000', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}** I understand what it is doing.  It looks like an array but I can't seem to access it like an array.

Comment: How do i insert data **"{map: map, strokeColor:'"+color+"', strokeWidth: 3, strokeOpacity: 0.5}"** does not work.